# module 'qiskit' has no attribute 'Aer'

Tags: python, qiskit

I'm using Google Colab to run my Python code. One month back, it worked fine. But now the same code through an error. I used `!pip install qiskit qiskit-aer`. The error is <module 'qiskit' has no attribute 'Aer'>

Can anyone help me to solve this error?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4li6p.png)

I solution to the error

Comment: Please post the error and code as text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Qiskit 1.0 changed from `from qiskit import Aer` to `from qiskit_aer import Aer`. See the [Qiskit 1.0 release notes](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/release-notes/1.0#misc-upgrade-notes), there may be additional adjustments that you have to update your code.